# How to get elements out of text that was just added with .html()

Tags: jquery

After I had text to an element with .html(), I want to immediately use .find() to get the individual elements out of my HTML and manipulate them. What do I have to change to the below code so that `elemBack` is a jQuery object instead of a "prevObject" as the Console is indicating.

```
(function($){
    $.widget("ui.ItemTest", {
        options: {
            elementId: null,
            id: null,
            front: null,
            back: null
        },
        _create: function(){
            this.element.html(this.display());
            console.log(this.element.html());
            var elemBack = $(this).find('.back');
            console.log(elemBack);
            $(this).find('.back').css('background-color','red'); //doesn't work
        },
        display: function() {
            var r = '';
            r += '<div class="front">'+this.options.front+'</div>';
            r += '<div class="back">'+this.options.back+'</div>';
            return r;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried: `var elemBack = this.element.find('.back')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `this.element` because `this` points to the widget, not the element

```
this.element.find('.back').css('background-color','red');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7GLCP/)